# Rails: collecting data from three relating models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm a noob trying to build up my first rails app. It's a "betting game" where users try to predict football results and get points for correct result or correct "tendency" (win, draw, loose).

Creating and updating bets is working fine, also creating games and inserting results as an admin user. But I'm having problems in displaying all bets from all users for each game in a kind of an index page, which should roughly look like this:

```
                       |  User1 |  User2 |  User3    ...
Game            Result |  Bet   |  Bet   |  Bet  
Team1 : Team2   1:0    |  1:1   |  3:2   |  1:0 
Team3 : Team4   1:2    |  1:2   |  -:-   |  3:0 
Team5 : Team6   -:-    |  1:2   |  -:-   |  3:0 
...
```

My Model structure looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bets

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bets

class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
belongs_to :game, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'game_id'
```

Indicated by the -:- in the above scetch, not every user will have placed a bet on every game, and not every game will have a result.

I tried a thousand ways of getting the data together for the index view and got issues with multiple errors (nil object, no method etc.). The current (not working) approach is getting everything in the controller:

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    @games = Game.all
    @bets = Bet.all
end
```

and in the view trying to iterate to the games and within each games through the users and bets in the view, while checking if a bet of a user and a game exists, which leads to unreadable messy code there:

```
    <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= game.home_team %> - <%= game.away_team %></td>
        <td>
            <% if game.away_score.nil? %>
                -:-
            <% else %>
                <%= game.home_score %> : <%= game.away_score %>
            <% end -%>
        </td>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <% bet = Bet.where( :user_id => user.id, :game_id => game.id) %>
            <% if bet.exists? %>
                <td><%= bet.home_bet %> : <%= bet.away_bet %></td>              
            <% else %>
                <td>-:-</td>
            <% end -%>
        <% end -%>
    </tr>
<% end -%>
```

I hope you can suggest a cleaner way to accomplish this. Unfortunately, none of the dozens of posts I read could solve my problem.

So, the first question is: what is the best way to retrieve the needed data from the different tables? Corresponding second Question: Is it best to build the data in the controller and pass it to the view or put it all together in the view?

I'm using rails 3.1.1 with squlite3.
I hope, someone can help this stupid newbee...

Comment: Could you post some of the things that you've tried to do to assemble the data in the controller?  Unless your collection of users is going to be pretty small, having your users trail horizontally isn't going to scale very well.  Will all of your users have bet on all of the games?  If they have, then you can just create a table, assign each row to a game, and iterate through your bets and drop them in cells...

Comment: just edited: no, not all users will have a bet on each game, which seems to cause the main problems. Since the users will be organized in communities (with about 10 members) later on, I hope the horizontal layout will fit, but thats not the main issue at the moment. I will post some examples later, since I don't have all the code in front of me now. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Just so you know, the `class_name` and `foreign_key` options aren't needed in your case. They're automatically inferred from the name of the association (`belongs_to :game`), and are only needed when the association name is *different* than the model name or key name.

Comment: @Andrew: I know, this was a result of reading a lot about rails relations and trying out different things. But thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I don't have time right now to post a full answer, but I'd suggest a `has_many :through` relationship, as in `Game has_many Users :through => :bets`. Then you can get everything through `Game.all` (and clean up your views by replacing the if statements with a call to a model or helper that returns the correct thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

controller:

```
@users = User.all
@game_bets = Game.all.map { |game| [game, game.bets.index_by(&:user)] }
```

view:

```
<% @game_bets.each do |game, bets| %>
  ...
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if bets.has_key?(user) %>
      <td><%= bets[user].home_bet %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>-:-</td>
...
```

Comment: This is likely to be very slow if there are lots of users. Iterating through all users shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @MarkThomas OP intended to display all users/games on one screen so speed was not an issue obviously.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Not quite. He wanted to display all users *associated* with each game. If there are users not associated with games at any particular moment, and that number can get large, then it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

So many issues here... let's start

1. there's no need to iterate through ALL users for EACH game. You can iterate through `game.bets` and for each 'bet' get a user by `bet.user`, according to the relationship you have built
2. To answer your 1st question: since you are trying to make a 'report' kind of a view with an intent to show 'all' games, your approach to have `@games = Game.all` is right. You don't need 2 other `.all` collections though since you can infer the data from the relationships
3. 2nd question: In Rails it is considered a good approach to have 'fat models, skinny controllers' which means that your data crunching/logic code should be in a model and controller should have only code used by the correspondent views.
4. About your view: In your case your view is not terribly bad since you have a sparsely populated tables and you should use `if`s for cases where score is not available etc

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, that helped a lot! Maybe my view are not that messy... :-)